# Fact table not populating with data

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create and populate three dimensions and a fact tables with data. The dimensions work just fine but i'm unable to get any data into my fact table. If anyone will be so kind to point out what i'm doing wrong -  i will be grateful.

Thank you all very much.

```
create table Customer
(
    CUID integer identity(1,1) primary key,
    Name varchar (25)  
)
insert into Customer select distinct  customer  from [Data]

create table Agent
(
    AID integer identity(1,1) primary key,
    Agent varchar (25)  
)
insert into Agent select distinct Seller from [Data]

create table Time
(
    TID integer identity(1,1) primary key,
    Week varchar (25),
    Month varchar (25),
    Year int 
)
insert into Time
    (Week,Month,Year)
    select distinct Day,Month,Year from [Data]

Create Table Fact
(
    CUID integer,
    AID integer,
    TID integer,
    Sale money,
    constraint pk_Fact primary key (CUID, AID, TID),
    constraint fk1_Fact foreign key (CUID)
        references Customer (CUID),
    constraint fk2_Fact foreign key (AID)
        references Agent (AID),
    constraint fk3_Fact foreign key (TID)
        references Time (TID),
)
insert into Fact
    (CUID, AID, TID, Sale)
    SELECT CUID, AID, TID, Sale
        FROM Customer, 
             Agent,
             Time,
             [Data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the cubes. Open it in a Visual Studio 2008 and process it. After that the data will be visible. Did you see the Dimension's mapping with the measures are correct?

Comment: I think that process is beyond the scope of what i need to do

Comment: You can process the cube, by opening Analysis Services in a SQL Server and then right click on the DB for which you want to populate data and then Process it. Without processing the data it cannot prepare the statistical data and can't show you. You must have to Process it atleast one time.

Comment: Thank you sir but the problem is i do get data sometimes when i run it just way too many records.So i know what i'm doing wrong would probably be something basic.